# Change foreground color of TreeView node from a seperated Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, treeview

With the following code I fill a Treeview with a root node and several child nodes in the MainForm LoadEvent. With the button btnPing I go through the nodes and search for child nodes with level 2. These nodes are then queried with My.computer.network.ping and the ForeColor of the ChildNode is colored according to the result red or green. The whole works synonymous. However, the GUI freezes me every time.

```
    '### TreeView Test
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Public Partial Class MainForm
    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

'### Hauptprogramm wird geladen ###
    Sub MainFormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
'Treeview befüllen
With treeView1
.Nodes.Add("Test1")
.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Test1_a")
.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Test1_b")
.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Test1_c")
.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("10.23.59.1")
.Nodes(0).Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("10.23.59.90")
.Nodes(0).Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("10.23.59.90")
.Nodes(0).Nodes(2).Nodes.Add("10.23.59.10")
.Nodes(0).Nodes(2).Nodes.Add("10.23.59.11")
.Nodes(0).Nodes(2).Nodes.Add("10.23.59.12")
.Nodes(0).Nodes(2).Nodes.Add("10.23.59.13")
.Nodes(0).Nodes(2).Nodes.Add("10.23.59.14")
End With
'Treeview aufklappen
treeView1.ExpandAll
End Sub

'### Sub zum rekursiven durchsuchen der Nodes ###
    Private Sub RecurseNodes(ByVal col As TreeNodeCollection)
        For Each tn As TreeNode In col             
        If tn.Level = 2 Then
            Try
            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(tn.Text) Then
                tn.ForeColor = Color.Green
                tn.StateImageIndex= 4
            Else    
                tn.ForeColor = Color.Red
                tn.StateImageIndex=5
            End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                tn.ForeColor = Color.Red
                tn.StateImageIndex=5
            End Try
        End If

        If tn.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            RecurseNodes(tn.Nodes)
        End If
        Next tn
    End Sub

'### Button zum starten der rekursiven Suche ###
    Sub BtnPingClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Treeview rekursiv durchsuchen
        RecurseNodes(treeView1.Nodes)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I would like to convert the whole so that the Ping runs in a separate thread. Now I have only one understanding question about the process. Can I start a thread with parameter transfer? Then I would run through the list and start with each node with level 2 a thread and wait for feedback. How would the best approach be?

Best Regards
Kay

Comment: Just don't, the Ping class already [knows how to do that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xya3e0zf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).  Use the PingCompleted event to update your UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
Sub BtnPingClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Treeview rekursiv durchsuchen
    RecurseNodes(TreeView1.Nodes)
End Sub

Private Async Sub RecurseNodes(ByVal col As TreeNodeCollection)
    For Each tn As TreeNode In col
        If tn.Level = 2 Then
            Dim T As Task(Of Boolean) = Ping(tn.Text)
            Await T
            tn.ForeColor = If(T.Result, Color.Green, Color.Red)
            tn.StateImageIndex = If(T.Result, 4, 5)
        ElseIf tn.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            RecurseNodes(tn.Nodes)
        End If
    Next tn
End Sub

Private Function Ping(ByVal ip As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Return Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Boolean)(
        Function() As Boolean
            Try
                Return My.Computer.Network.Ping(ip)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return False
            End Try
        End Function)
End Function
```

Comment: You are trying to access the UI from a task which doesn't work.

Comment: Where?...I'm not accessing the UI from the Task.  Please elaborate @dbasnett

Comment: In the Using block.

Comment: We've returned from the Task already (and are back on the UI thread) by the time we hit those lines. @dbasnett

Comment: I did try the code; it worked fine, no errors and my UI was responsive.  Changed the code to make it clearer what is happening. @dbasnett

Comment: It seems to only fail sometimes.  Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
                                 RecurseNodes(TreeView1.Nodes(0))
                             End Sub)
End Sub

Private Sub RecurseNodes(ByVal col As TreeNode)
    For Each tn As TreeNode In col.Nodes
        If tn.Level < 2 AndAlso tn.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            RecurseNodes(tn)
        ElseIf tn.Level = 2 Then
            Dim tp As Task
            tp = Task.Run(Sub()
                              Dim c As Color
                              Dim idx As Integer
                              Try
                                  If My.Computer.Network.Ping(tn.Text) Then
                                      c = Color.Green
                                      idx = 4
                                  Else
                                      c = Color.Red
                                      idx = 5
                                  End If
                              Catch ex As Exception
                                  c = Color.Red
                                  idx = 5
                              End Try
                              Me.Invoke(Sub()
                                            tn.ForeColor = c
                                            tn.StateImageIndex = idx
                                        End Sub)
                          End Sub)
        End If
    Next tn
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get an 3 errors: Task is not defined. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Kay What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: .net 4 i am using

Comment: @Kay At the beginning of the code add this Imports System.Threading.Tasks